# biblatex-chicago: Change translator and editor description in the bibliography

Tags: biblatex, biber

I had some issues with cbyeditor and cbytranslator where I got the warning "Package biblatex Warning: Bibliography string 'cbyeditor' undefined". That I managed to fix and now my footnotes looks good. I used the following solution:

```
\NewBibliographyString{cbytranslator}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{danish}{cbytranslator = {trans.}}
\NewBibliographyString{cbyeditor}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{danish}{cbyeditor = {red.}}
```

Unfortunately, another translation appears in the bibliography. The translation in the footnotes is perfect and just the way I want them:

```
3. Mary Pardo, „The Subject of Savoldo’s Magdalene“, i Sixteenth-Century Italian Art, *red.* Michael W. Cole, Blackwell Anthologies in Art History 3 (Malden, MA: Blackwell Publishing, 2006), 445.
```

Whereas this entry differs in the Bibliography:

```
Pardo, Mary. „The Subject of Savoldo’s Magdalene“. I Sixteenth-Century Italian Art, *udgivet af* Michael W. Cole, 441–484. Blackwell Anthologies in Art History 3. Malden, MA: Blackwell Publishing, 2006.
```

In the bibliography it says *udgivet af* instead of *red.* as I have specified above. How can I change my cbytranslator and cbyeditor so the bibliography reflects the way I've done it in the footnotes?

Comment: Based on the contents of `danish.lbx` it seems that in the bibliography you get the string `byeditor` (and `bytranslator ` as well as all the compound forms) in the bibliography, you will have to change that one as well. If that does not help you, an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) we can investigate in more detail would be greatly appreciated. (Indeed, it seems to me that `cbyeditor` is the cite-version of `byeditor`, note that there are much more `cby...` strings, cf. `chicago-american.lbx`, you only get warnings about the ones you actually use.)

Comment: Did that work for you? If so a short heads-up would be appreciated. If not, any further hints are appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, and my apologies for not getting back to you. It was very helpful, and I guess that the c (as in cbyeditor) stands for cite or referring to the cite command. Is there away I can vote up your comment, so other people easily can see that you answer is helpful?

Comment: Thanks. As far as I can see, my vote will be displayed when my reputation score reaches 15. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, you cannot up-vote right now, you can accept the answer using the green checkmark though.

Comment: Ah! Perfect :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`biblatex-chicago` defines different bibstrings for use in citations and in the bibliography.

In the bibliography the standard strings like `byeditor`, `bytranslator` are used; but if such a string is needed in citations, `cbyeditor`, `cbytranslator` and friends are applied.

So when you change `cby...` strings you should make sure their `by...` counterpart is in line with this change (and vice versa).

```
\NewBibliographyString{cbytranslator}
\NewBibliographyString{cbyeditor}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{danish}{%
  cbyeditor = {red\adddot},
  cbyeditor = {red\adddot},
  cbytranslator = {trans\adddot},
  bytranslator = {trans\adddot},
}
```

Note that there are many more `by...` strings as well as `cby...` strings defined in `english.lbx` and `chicago-american.lbx` (or `danish.lbx`, note that `biblatex-chicago` doesn't have a Danish localisation file, so you will have to provide all needed strings manually, you will be warned about them in the `.log` as well as via the visual hint that the strings names are displayed in bold face).
Have a look at those files to see which strings need changing.