# How to replace "trans. by" with just "trans." in biblatex-philosophy?

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-philosophy

How can I replace "trans. by" with just "trans." in `biblatex-philosophy`?

Here's the format I need:
[image: Target]

I'm most of the way there with the following:

```
documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{scrartcl}

% Bibliography preamble
\usepackage[giveninits=true, style=philosophy-modern]{biblatex}  
\addbibresource{testbib.bib}

% Some tweaks I've already made
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}% no postnote prefix in "normal" citation commands
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}% no postnote prefix in "multicite" commands
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}% no prefix for the `pages` field in the bibliography

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1} % Remove quotations from Article title
\setlength{\yeartitle}{5.4em} % Set greater spacing between the year and the title
\setlength{\postnamesep}{2.5ex plus 2pt minus 1pt}

\begin{document}
Sentence containing citation \parencite{pavese1965}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and `.bib` file:

```
@book{pavese1965,
    Author = {Pavese, Cesare},
    Publisher = {University of Michigan Press},
    Title = {Dialogues with Leucò},
    date = {1965},
    Editor = {William Arrowsmith and D. S. Carne-Ross},
    editortype = {translator},
    Location = {Ann Arbor}}
```

Which outputs:

[image: Attempt]

Any help with removing that single pesky word would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add:

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  bytranslator = {trans\adddot},
}
```

But I think your question is a duplicate of [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280122/biblatex-chicago-change-translator-and-editor-description-in-the-bibliography/280850#280850).

```
\begin{filecontents}{testbib.bib}
@book{pavese1965,
    Author = {Pavese, Cesare},
    Publisher = {University of Michigan Press},
    Title = {Dialogues with Leucò},
    date = {1965},
    Editor = {William Arrowsmith and D. S. Carne-Ross},
    editortype = {translator},
    Location = {Ann Arbor}}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{scrartcl}

% Bibliography preamble
\usepackage[giveninits=true, style=philosophy-modern]{biblatex}  
\addbibresource{testbib.bib}

% Some tweaks I've already made
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}% no postnote prefix in "normal" citation commands
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}% no postnote prefix in "multicite" commands
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}% no prefix for the `pages` field in the bibliography

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1} % Remove quotations from Article title
\setlength{\yeartitle}{5.4em} % Set greater spacing between the year and the title
\setlength{\postnamesep}{2.5ex plus 2pt minus 1pt}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  bytranslator = {trans\adddot},
}

\begin{document}
Sentence containing citation \parencite{pavese1965}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I did see that other question, but in my ignorance, thought the answer was specific to biblatex-chicago. I've found the \DefineBibliographyStrings documentation and it's making much more sense - cheers!

Comment: @anunlikelypseudonym Don't worry, you're a very clever new user. We rarely see a complete MWE with bibliography!

Comment: Ha, thanks - just trying to help you help me :-)

Comment: @anunlikelypseudonym Indeed, very few new (sometimes also old) users understand that clear questions with a complete MWE are answered more quickly! :):):)