# Howto use babel 'dutch', biblatex and chicago-notes at the same time?

Tags: babel, biblatex-chicago

I started to learn LaTeX in the hope to gain speed and accuracy with references in my philosophical articles. But after five days struggling I am still stuck. Of course I am trying to do complex things without knowing all the basics, but hey! I am an engineer, so I don't do manuals from beginning to the end :-)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,dutch]{article}
%\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage[style=chicago-authordate,babel=other, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\addbibresource{./myreferences.bib}
```

When I compile like this the bibliography works fine and uses Dutch, but the footnotes are (of course) Chicago style authordate. The footnote that uses the Dutch translation of 'Translated by' works perfect.

**What is the name of the chicagostyle notes?**
I tried *chicago-notes* but then I received warnings:

> 'babel/polyglossia' detected but 'csquotes' missing.
>
> Bibliography string 'cbytranslator' undefined(biblatex) at entry 'Foo'

Using the other `\usepackage` (line 2) and commenting out the other (line 3), I get the same warnings, and in this case in the footnote the **cbytranslator** is not resolved. (I did even reinstall `csquotes` from CTAN).

**cbytranslator** should give me the dutch translation of 'Translated by'.
Can someone give me a hint or a solution?? Thank you very much!

Edited: Maybe my `myreference.bib` entry is incorrect?

```
@mvbook{Foo,
    author = {Plato},
    title = {De Staat},
    date = {2009},
    translator = {Xavier De Win},
    titleaddon = {Alcibiades I – De Staat – De Staatsman – Critias},
    volumes = {3},
    publisher = {Pelckmans},
    location = {Kapellen},
}
```

Here is a snippet:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,dutch]{article}

\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{csquotes}

%\usepackage[style=chicago-notes,babel=dutch, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage[dutch]{babel}

\addbibresource{./myreferences.bib}

\begin{document}
    
    \null\vfill% just for the example
    
    This is some text.\footcite{Foo} 

\printbibliography    
\end{document}
```

Comment: As always on the site you are much more likely to get help if you provide a full minimal example instead of the sniplet above

Comment: I found the problem of the missing csquotes: I put it in /usr/local/share/texmf , later I tried /usr/share/texmf , but it finally worked when I put it in /home/<my_name>/texmf . I really don't understand why something like that should be stored in my home directory, but alas!

Comment: Never ever update your LaTeX installation manually! that is why we have package managers both on the latex side and on the Linux side.

Comment: Sorry guys, I think I am waisting my time by trying. Maybe Texstudio didn't install everything correctly, maybe the dutch language is not fully supported.
In the bibliography it works with dutch texts, but not in the citations in the footnote. I will declare this question as closed, as it has no point in researching this any further. I am not a bibtex programmer. See you!

Comment: Welcome!It is not TeXstudio which installs packages (it is only a TeX-dedicated editor), but the package manager of  your distribution. Did you think of adding the option `[autocite=footnote]` the default is `inline`)?

Answer (score 1):

The warning

> ```
> 'babel/polyglossia' detected but 'csquotes' missing.
> ```

is unrelated to the main issue at hand here, but it is still a good idea to load `csquotes` with `biblatex`. (As discussed in the comments you should not have to install the package manually. Install packages through your distribution - `tlmgr` or MikTeX Console.)

---

The main issue here is that `biblatex-chicago` has no Dutch localisation. Standard `biblatex` has a Dutch localisation, so most things still work fine, but some `biblatex-chicago`-specific strings may not be available. One of these strings is `cbytranslator`. That's why you get the warning

> ```
> Package biblatex Warning: Bibliography string 'cbytranslator' undefined
> (biblatex)                at entry 'destaat' on input line 25.
> ```

If you want full support for all translations needed by `biblatex-chicago`, you can get one of its `.lbx` files (for example from CTAN: https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-chicago/latex/lbx) and translate it into Dutch. If you complete the file, you may want to contact the author of `biblatex-chicago` and ask him to include it into his package.

If you only want this document to come out OK, you can define the required strings (those that `biblatex` warns about) on the fly.

First you need to declare the missing string with

```
\NewBibliographyString{<bibstring>}
```

and then you need to give its translation in

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{dutch}{
  <bibstring> = {<Dutch translation>},
}
```

The full definition of the `cbytranslator` bibstring is a bit more tricky than usual, so I included a more straightforward example as well. See also [biblatex-chicago: Change translator and editor description in the bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/280122/35864).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,dutch]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}

\NewBibliographyString{cbyeditor}
\NewBibliographyString{cbytranslator}
\makeatletter
\DefineBibliographyStrings{dutch}{
  cbyeditor     = {geredigeerd door},
  cbytranslator = {\lbx@fromlang\ vertaald door},
}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@mvbook{destaat,
  author     = {Plato},
  title      = {De Staat},
  date       = {2009},
  translator = {Xavier De Win},
  titleaddon = {Alcibiades I – De Staat – De Staatsman – Critias},
  volumes    = {3},
  publisher  = {Pelckmans},
  location   = {Kapellen},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \null\vfill% just for the example

  This is some text.\autocite{destaat} 

  \printbibliography  
\end{document}
```

Note that the issue mainly occurs in the citations, since `biblatex-chicago` defines new bibstrings for citations, but uses existing strings for the bibliography.

[image: Plato, De Staat, Alcibiades I – De Staat – De Staatsman – Critias, vertaald door Xavier De Win, 3 delen (Kapellen: Pelckmans, 2009).]

---

In general it is recommended to load the style of `biblatex-chicago` via the wrapper package, i.e.

```
\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}
```

or

```
\usepackage[authordate]{biblatex-chicago}
```

and not via `biblatex` directly (as in `\usepackage[style=chicago-authordate,babel=other, backend=biber]{biblatex}`), since the wrapper package automatically sets all required options.